# send email in Meteor app with mailGun - Error invoking Method 'sendEmail'

Tags: meteor, compiler-errors, email, mailgun

I use Meteor v1 to buid un app, and to be able to send a email from my app, I add Email package. 
This is my code on the client

```
Template.Home.events({
    'click button': function(event, template){
        event.preventDefault();


         var depart = template.find('[id=exampleInputEmail1]').value;
         var arrive = template.find('[id=exampleInputPassword1]').value;
         var email = template.find('[id=exampleInputPassword1m]').value;
         var nom = template.find('[id=exampleInputPassword1s]').value;
         var telephone = template.find('[id=exampleInputPassword1n]').value;
         var element = template.find('[id=exampleInputPassword1j]').value;



      Meteor.call('sendEmail', 'nwabdou85@yahoo.fr', email, 'Faites moi un devis rapide svp', 'This is a test of Email.send.');

    }

});
```

And the server one is

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    var username = "postmaster%40sandboxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org";
    var password = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    var server = "smtp.mailgun.org";
    var port = "587"

   process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(server) + ':' + port;  
});
// In your server code: define a method that the client can call
Meteor.methods({
  'sendEmail': function (to, from, subject, text) {
    // check([to, from, subject, text], [String]);
    this.unblock();

    Email.send({
      to: to,
      from: from,
      subject: subject,
      text: text
    });
  }
});
```

but it does not work !! it throw out this error on consol : Error invoking Method 'sendEmail': Internal server error [500]

Can you even have this issue and hwo do you fixe it ??

Comment: Have you checked the server logs? Why not set the MAIL_URL as a true environment variable? Where are you hosting the app?

Comment: For the two first questions: I dont know how to do; for the 3: I host it on meteor.com :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest switching your hosting to Heroku, which is free but more configurable. Try reading my recent article on the subject, should give you some hints: http://joshowens.me/modulus-vs-heroku-vs-digital-ocean/.

Comment: Thanks I ll do, but my app even locally, send email doesnot work!!

Answer (score 0):

If that is a 500 error from mailgun then  its something on their side not yours. try accessing your dashboard on mailgun and see if you can get some info from there. I spent abit of time trying to get this right and it was all to do with getting the Mail url correct.

Comment: this error was on the console, In Mailgun s log there is nothing ; (

Answer (score 0):

I remember in the bulletproof meteor you should use **Meteor.defer** function to delay your email sending process. Usually sending email caused response timeout.

Again, this.unblock might not useful in this case. Please try to comment out it if the first way doesn't work.

Comment: To be honest, I dont know how to use meteor.defer even if I google it but I dont find something helpful;  however, even I dont change anything but it works again :)

Answer (score 0):

`encodeURIcomponent` would convert something from `sam@sam.com` to `sam%40sam.com`.

Your `username` is already URI encoded, so doesn't need to be further encoded. In this case, you are double encoding the username, and hence was probably failing with an authentication error.